# how to specify setter injection for a static class using StructureMap?

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, static-members

I'm currently working through this code snippet from a design patterns book:

```
public static class DomainEvents
{
    public static IDomainEventHandlerFactory DomainEventHandlerFactory { get; set; }

    public static void Raise<T>(T domainEvent) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        DomainEventHandlerFactory.GetDomainEventHandlersFor(domainEvent).ForEach(h => h.Handle(domainEvent));
    }
}
```

This deals with wiring up DomainEvents, and this particular code snippet is responsible allowing me to raise an event via the `Raise` method on DomainEvents.

Here is the code in my Bootstrapper file:

```
public class ControllerRegistry : Registry
{
        public ControllerRegistry()
        {
            ForRequestedType<IDomainEventHandlerFactory>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<StructureMapDomainEventHandlerFactory>();
            ForRequestedType<IDomainEventHandler<OrderSubmittedEvent>>().AddConcreteType<OrderSubmittedHandler>();
        }
    }
```

When I go to access `DomainEvents.Raise` from my Service layer (in this example, I'm raising the `OrderSumittedEvent`), `DomainEvents` is `null` (when it should be set via StructureMap):

```
public class OrderService
{
    public void Create(Order order)
    {
        DomainEvents.Raise(new OrderSubmittedEvent() { Order = order });
    }
}
```

Unless I explicitly set the `DomainEvents.DomainEventHandlerFactory` by hand to `StructureMapDomainEventHandlerFactory` like this:

```
public class OrderService
{
    public void Create(Order order)
    {
        // this is the manual assignment I have to make into the DomainEventHandlerFactory of
        // the static DomainEvents class. Basically, this is what StructureMap should take care
        // of for me, but is not.
        DomainEvents.DomainEventHandlerFactory = new StructureMapDomainEventHandlerFactory();

        DomainEvents.Raise(new OrderSubmittedEvent() { Order = order });
    }
}
```

Below is the output of StrucutureMap using `.WhatDoIHave()`, and it appears that StructureMap does have a configured instance of `StructureMapDomainEventHandlerFactory` for type `IDomainEventHandlerFactory`. Here is the dump:

```
================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
PluginType                                                                                  Name                                                                                                                          Description                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Func`1<TResult> (Func`1<TResult>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Scoped as:  Transient

                                                                                        311731d7-60c7-46de-9ef4-24608f21df04                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IDomainEventHandlerFactory (DE.Infrastructure.Domain.Events.IDomainEventHandlerFactory)     dbcb010c-fa92-4137-85b8-161ab17c2c98                                                                                          Configured Instance of DE.Infrastructure.Domain.Events.StructureMapDomainEventHandlerFactory, DE.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Scoped as:  Transient

                                                                                            dbcb010c-fa92-4137-85b8-161ab17c2c98                                                                                          Configured Instance of DE.Infrastructure.Domain.Events.StructureMapDomainEventHandlerFactory, DE.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IDomainEventHandler`1<OrderSubmittedEvent> (IDomainEventHandler`1<OrderSubmittedEvent>)     DE.Services.DomainEventHandlers.OrderSubmittedHandler, DE.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null     Configured Instance of DE.Services.DomainEventHandlers.OrderSubmittedHandler, DE.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null                      
Scoped as:  Transient

                                                                                            DE.Services.DomainEventHandlers.OrderSubmittedHandler, DE.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null     Configured Instance of DE.Services.DomainEventHandlers.OrderSubmittedHandler, DE.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IContainer (StructureMap.IContainer)                                                        e24f9e45-caaf-48b6-89f7-d8125310102a                                                                                          Object:  StructureMap.Container                                                                                                                                       
Scoped as:  Transient

                                                                                            e24f9e45-caaf-48b6-89f7-d8125310102a                                                                                          Object:  StructureMap.Container                                                                                                                                       
================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
```

I've used StructureMap, but I haven't used Setter Injection, nor have I had to deal with using StructureMap with static classes (if that even makes sense), so I'm a little lost as to why this code won't work.

Is it possible to use Setter Injection with a static implementation of a class like this? 
Am I not using StructureMap properly?
Should StructureMap be responsible for creating the DomainEvents class as a Singleton, and I can get rid of the static implementation?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: what was the verdict for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use Setter Injection with a static implementation of a class like this?

No. It is only possible with createable classes.

> Am I not using StructureMap properly?

You are not. Dependency injection deals with *creating and providing instances*. By definition static classes are non-createable in code and therefore, non-injectable.

> Should StructureMap be responsible for creating the DomainEvents class as a Singleton, and I can get rid of the static implementation?

It looks like a core feature of this design is to use a single instance so the event is only fired once. I am not sure what design pattern you are going for, but in many cases you can substitute `Action<T>` or `Func<T>` for events, and if you use the singleton lifestyle properly you can probably register a single instance that can be shared between all of your classes rather than resorting to a static class.

If the static event is absolutely required, you can inject an instance of IDomainEventHandlerFactory in your application startup code by resolving the instance and setting it manually after you have completed your registration code (in your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)).

```
// Provide the DI container with configuration
var container = DIConfig();

// Set the static event
DomainEvents.DomainEventHandlerFactory = container.Resolve<IDomainEventHandlerFactory>();
```

To ensure your application doesn't abuse the setter by calling it more than once or using it before it is set, you can put some guard clauses in your static class.

```
public static class DomainEvents
{
    private static IDomainEventHandlerFactory domainEventHandlerFactory;

    public static IDomainEventHandlerFactory DomainEventHandlerFactory 
    { 
        get
        {
            return domainEventHandlerFactory;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            if (domainEventHandlerFactory != null)
                throw new ArgumentException("DomainEventHandlerFactory is already set and cannot be set again.");
            domainEventHandlerFactory = value;
        }
    }

    public static void Raise<T>(T domainEvent) where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        ThrowIfNotInitialized()
        DomainEventHandlerFactory.GetDomainEventHandlersFor(domainEvent).ForEach(h => h.Handle(domainEvent));
    }

    private static void ThrowIfNotInitialized()
    {
        if (domainEventHandlerFactory == null)
        {
            throw new MvcSiteMapException("Not initialized. You must set DomainEventHandlerFactory at application start.");
        }
    }
}
```